QR Codes are being scanned by QRCode pro
On my iPhone, QRCode pro is launched when I scan a QR Code from Camera.  It then tries to access Adobe Cloud for which I do not have a subscription.
Maybe I installed this long ago? I ant to remove the app and then be able to use the camera for QR scanning again.  Any tips on how to do this?

What exactly do you need tips for? Uninstalling an app should be straightforward, is there something else which needs solving?

I could not find the app to uninstall it. I'm looking again now.

You can use the search functionality and then delete it from there the usual way.

It does not show up on Home Screen or in iphone Storage. I'll come back to this later.

If there's an app doing things you don't expect, you need to uninstall it.
You can scan QR codes from the Camera app without any 3rd party applications installed.
